# Custom TextView alignment

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I wrote a small custom text view in order to use it on a list. There are three States depending on which i want to have this:

State 1 -> just the text, for example TEST_TEXT

State 2 -> a drawable start, a color background and the same text TEST_TEXT

State 3 -> a different drawable start, different color background and the same text TEST_TEXT

The text has always the same value (TEST_TEXT)

But with my implementation i lost the alignment and as a result the text on the state that
i do not have a drawable start is not align with the others that have drawable as you can see on the image below. I want all of them to be start align.

[image: lost start alignmnet]

Is there a way to achieve it?

My custom text view class is :

```
enum class State {
    STATE_ONE,
    STATE_TWO,
    STATE_THREE
}

class CustomTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
): TextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val PADDING = 4 * resources.displayMetrics.density
    private val ZERO_PADDING = 0 * resources.displayMetrics.density

    var state: State = State.STATE_ONE
        set(value) {
            field = value
            updateTextView()
            invalidate()
        }

    private fun updateTextView() {
        when(state) {
            State.STATE_TWO -> {
                this.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_red)
                this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_baseline_message_24, 0, 0, 0)
                this.compoundDrawablePadding = PADDING.toInt()
                this.setPadding(PADDING.toInt(), PADDING.toInt(), PADDING.toInt(), PADDING.toInt())
            }
            State.STATE_THREE -> {
                this.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorGreenBright)
                this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_baseline_message_24, 0, 0, 0)
                this.compoundDrawablePadding = PADDING.toInt()
                this.setPadding(PADDING.toInt(), PADDING.toInt(), PADDING.toInt(), PADDING.toInt())
            }
            else -> {
                this.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent)
                this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null)
                this.compoundDrawablePadding = PADDING.toInt()
                this.setPadding(ZERO_PADDING.toInt(), ZERO_PADDING.toInt(), ZERO_PADDING.toInt(), ZERO_PADDING.toInt())

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The layout where i add them is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <custom.textView.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST_TEXT"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_rounded_text_bg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

    <custom.textView.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST_TEXT"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_rounded_text_bg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewOne"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <custom.textView.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST_TEXT"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_rounded_text_bg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTwo"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and finally my activity is simple like this:

```
class CustomTextActivity: BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityCustomTextBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(getView())
        initLayout()
    }

    override fun getView(): View {
        binding = ActivityCustomTextBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun initLayout() {
        binding.textViewOne.state = State.STATE_ONE
        binding.textViewTwo.state = State.STATE_TWO
        binding.textViewThree.state = State.STATE_THREE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, if you want to have the same alignment, even without inner drawables, you have 2 options:

- right align the text
- display a "fake drawable" in the first case

Comment: thanks for the response. Not the best solution but as i did not found any better solution i add a "fake drawable" in the first case.